# Multiple projects (and fig.yml) linking to same database

Tags: docker, dockerfile, fig

**Example of file structure:**

```
projects
 |-- project 1
 |    |-- app
 |    |    +-- <all app files>
 |    |-- Dockerfile  
 |    +-- fig.yml
 +-- project 2
     |-- app
     |    +-- <all app files>
     |-- Dockerfile  
     +-- fig.yml
```

**Dockerfile** (not exactly what I'll use but just an example)

```
FROM node:latest 

RUN mkdir /src

RUN npm install nodemon -g

WORKDIR /src
ADD app/package.json /src/package.json
RUN npm install

ADD app/nodemon.json /src/nodemon.json

EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm start
```

**fig.yml**

```
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - "app:/src/app"
  ports:
    - "3030:3000" # ports different for both apps
  links:
    - db
db:
  image: library/mysql
  <other db config>
```

---

**Question**: Is there a way to have these two projects connect to the same mysql container? Right now it would create one mysql container per project.

Comment: Not right now, but there are proposals to add that kind of support https://github.com/docker/fig/pull/758

Answer (score 4):

You can use `external_links` in your YAML file as of docker-compose 1.1.0 ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#external_links)). You can have one project use an external link to the other project's db or have both projects link to an external container.

Example YAML for project 2:

```
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - "app:/src/app"
  ports:
    - "3030:3000" # ports different for both apps
  external_links:
    - project1_db_1:db
```